# how would a loop with a nested return be implemented in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm playing around with a crafty tutorial here:

http://buildnewgames.com/introduction-to-crafty/

and am wondering how this particular function be implemented in clojurescript/clojure

```js
 var max_villages = 5;
 for (var x = 0; x < Game.map_grid.width; x++) {
   for (var y = 0; y < Game.map_grid.height; y++) {
     if (Math.random() < 0.02) {
       Crafty.e('Village').at(x, y);

       if (Crafty('Village').length >= max_villages) {
        return;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that we can have the `(for [])` construct but how would you get it to stop when max_villages hits 5?

Comment: Interesting, is SO's syntax highlighting based on the question tag? It's seems to think semicolons are comments

Comment: @jozefg It uses a few things, but yes it uses the tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
(def max-villages 5)

(->> (for [x (range map-width)
           y (range map-height)]
       [x y])
     (filter (fn [_] (< (rand) 0.02)))
     (take max-villages))
```

Then perhaps add `(map make-village-at)` or something similar as the next stage of the pipeline; if it's meant to perform side effects, add a `dorun` or `doall` as the final stage to force them to happen at once (choosing one or the other depending on whether the return values are interesting).

NB. some extra vectors and random numbers may be generated due to seq chunking, it'll be less than 32 though.

A more imperative approach with a counter for comparison:

```
(let [counter (atom 0)]
  (doseq [x (range map-width)
          :while (< @counter max-villages)
          y (range map-height)
          :while (< @counter max-villages)
          :when (< (rand) 0.02)]
    (swap! counter inc)
    (prn [x y]))) ; call make-village-at here
```

`:while` terminates the loop at the current nesting level when its test expression fails; `:when` moves on to the next iteration immediately. `doseq` supports chunking too, but `:while` will prevent it from performing unnecessary work.

Comment: The version with `@counter` will work, but not for the reasons you intended: the `:while` will only "skip" the current `x` binding and move on to the next one, meaning that `counter` needs to be tested once for each `x` even though it never changes again. For small `map-width` that's fine, but for large (or infinite) widths it's a serious problem.

Comment: @amalloy Indeed, `x` needs its own `:while`! Thanks for spotting the bug, I'll fix it in a second. (Edit: done; also fixed the wording.)

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion it would be something like:

```
(letfn [(op [x y]
          (if (= (rand) 0.02)
            (do
              (village-at x y)
              (if (>= (village-length) max-villages) true))))]
  (loop [x 0 y 0]
    (when (and (< x width) (not (op x y)))
      (if (= (inc y) height)
        (recur (inc x) 0)
        (recur x (inc y))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a great tutorial!

A variation on Michael's approach (I would  have just commented to his answer but I don't have enough stack power yet) would be to use Cartesian products rather than nested for loops:

```
;; some stub stuff to get the example to run
(ns example.core
  (:use clojure.math.combinatorics))

(def max-villages 5)
(def map-width 10)
(def map-height 10)
(defn crafty-e [x y z] (print z))

;; the example, note I use doseq rather than map to empasize the fact that the loop 
;; is being performed for its side effects not its return value.
(doseq [coord (take max-villages 
                (filter 
                 (fn [_] (< (rand)  0.02))
                 (cartesian-product (range map-width) (range map-height))))]
(crafty-e :village :at coord))
```