# Call function for all possible combinations of vectors

Tags: dictionary, clojure, functional-programming

I have been using Clojure for the past week since I continued a project of a colleague of mine. We are using Clojure to generate some files. I am trying to refactor some code since he had to do it quickly and hardcoded most of the values. So I have:

```
(defn gen [a b] (...))
```

and I want to wrap that with something like

```
(defn gen-vector [a-vec b-vec] (...))
```

`gen_vector` is going to be my "main", meaning I will trigger the execution by writing something like

```
(gen-vector [1 2] [3 4])
```

and I expect to get all the combinations for `gen`, something like executing:

```
(gen 1 3)
(gen 1 4)
(gen 2 3)
(gen 2 4)
```

What I have so far is

```
(map #(gen %1 %2) countries fieldchar)
```

But that doesn't seen to do the trick since it does 1-3, 2-4 only. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Regards,
Dimi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a lazy seq of values of `(gen x y)`, use

```
(for [x x-vec
      y y-vec]
  (gen x y))
```

If `gen` were a function called for side effects with no useful return value, you'd want to replace `for` with `doseq`.

`for` and `doseq` in their basic form<sup>1</sup> evaluate their bodies for each tuple in the Cartesian product of the input sequences. `(map f xs ys ...)`, in contrast, traverses the sequences in lockstep, so that only the tuples of elements at matching positions in the sequences are used.

---

<sup>1</sup> There's also a mini-language for filtering (`:when`), stopping the loops early (`:while`) and introducing local bindings (`:let`) from inside the bindings vector. See `(doc for)` for an overview of the syntax and perhaps [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16599395/232707) for examples involving `:when` and `:while`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michal. This worked perfectly :) Cheers

Comment: No worries. Just added a comment on comprehensions vs. `map` and the filtering/binding mini-language for completeness.